# DeviceClient.GetTwinAsync returns a device Id and etag properties as null

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I try to get DeviceTwin properties DeviceClient.GetTwinAsync, however I always get deviceId and etag null from the GetTwinAsync() method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device twin - when accessed from the device-side - does only include the properties (desired and reported), not the tags, deviceid, etc.

See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/728) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#device-twins). Tags and the other fields are only available on the service-side.